# How to retrieve first instance of saved value as string?

Tags: python, django

What I am trying to do is retrieving the saved value from models as a string. I tried this way:

```
class ExternalKeys(models.Model):
    public = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    secret = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    webhook_secret = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
```

and called it in the views like this `stripe.api_key = ExternalKeys.objects.first().public`,
but this is not working.

However, if I do this way it prints the correct value to template:

```
def get_public_key(request):
    public = ExternalKeys.objects.first().public
    return render(request, 'templat.html', {'public': public})
```

How I can get this value as sting in the views?

Comment: Exactly what is not working? Note that `.first()` does not mean the first object saved. Without `.order_by(..)`, `.first()` can return any record.

Comment: even though the record is saved in db, it throws the error "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "client_apps_externalkeys" does not exist
LINE 1: ... "client_apps_externalkeys"."webhook_secret" FROM "client_ap...

Comment: then you either did not migrate properly, or you are accessing the wrong database (when you use multiple databases).

Comment: I am wondering how it happens, because as I said, I can see it saved in db and can retrieve in templates, but if i call stripe.api_key = ExternalKeys.objects.first().public, it throws this error. Even if i replace ExternalKey model with any other working model it also throws the same error. I am usnig postgres db and django tenant schemas